# Proper way to decode SecurityElement.Escape using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've tried several methods to decode encoded xml using javascript. For some reason all of them ignore ' which causes it to fail. I can do a string.replace to fix the issue, but wondering why this happens or if there is some other method I should be using.

I've tried decodeURIComponent as well as another method I found on SO that puts the content in a div and then pulls it back out. Both ignore the '. I also tried unescape which curiously did nothing whatsoever. It is an xml block I am decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I could find to do it since no one responded:

function HtmlDecode(input) {
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = input;
    return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue.replace(/'/g, "'");
}